# Pandas: describe() for datetime column

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `pandas` to perform data analysis, I have a `datetime` column and I am using `describe()` as below.

```
s = pd.Series([np.datetime64("2000-01-01"), np.datetime64("2010-01-01"), np.datetime64("2010-01-01")])
print('--------------------')
print(s)
print('--------------------')
print(s.dtype)
print('--------------------')
print(s.describe())
```

I am getting output as below:

```
--------------------
0   2000-01-01
1   2010-01-01
2   2010-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
--------------------
datetime64[ns]
--------------------
count                      3
mean     2006-09-01 08:00:00
min      2000-01-01 00:00:00
25%      2004-12-31 12:00:00
50%      2010-01-01 00:00:00
75%      2010-01-01 00:00:00
max      2010-01-01 00:00:00
dtype: object
```

I was going through documentation, The above output summary should be generated for `numeric` datatype as opposed to `non-numeric` datatypes like `object, category, timestamp` which have different summary.

pandas version:
`pandas = "^2.0.0"`

documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html

What I am missing, does `datetime` datatype is treated as `numeric` datatype inside `describe()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, internally datetime objects are stored as integers (number of nanoseconds since epoch), making them inherently numeric data.

For the reported data, all values (`['count', 'mean', 'min', '25%', '50%', '75%', 'max']`) are valid as they represent the count or a date in the min-max range. You can note that `std` is absent, since computing a standard deviation wouldn't make sense.

The behavior on datetime data is actually demonstrated in the [`describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) documentation:

> Describing a timestamp Series.
>
> ```
> s = pd.Series([
>     np.datetime64("2000-01-01"),
>     np.datetime64("2010-01-01"),
>     np.datetime64("2010-01-01")
> ])
>
> s.describe()
>
> count                      3
> mean     2006-09-01 08:00:00
> min      2000-01-01 00:00:00
> 25%      2004-12-31 12:00:00
> 50%      2010-01-01 00:00:00
> 75%      2010-01-01 00:00:00
> max      2010-01-01 00:00:00
> dtype: object
> ```

Internally, `describe` is handled in [`pandas/core/methods/describe.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.3/pandas/core/methods/describe.py). The [`select_describe_func`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.3/pandas/core/methods/describe.py#L354-L373) function is choosing how to handle the data based on the dtype and a specific approach ([`describe_timestamp_1d`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.3/pandas/core/methods/describe.py#L330-L351)) is used for datetime data.

Follow-up:

"*Using astype on the above example, if the datatype is set as datetime then summary is numeric and if the datatype is set as object then summary is non-numeric. So, In general while performing analysis on such column, do we set datatype as datetime or object, which is preferred?*"

When using `s.astype('object').describe()` you get the same behavior as you would have for strings:

```
s.astype('object').describe()

count                       3  # number of values
unique                      2  # number of unique values
top       2010-01-01 00:00:00  # most frequent value
freq                        2  # count of the most frequent value
dtype: object
```

It's up to you to determine which behavior you need, if you use your dates as datetime information then keep the original type, if you use them as a Categorical (for instance if you have 2 or 3 different dates and their absolute value is not meaningful other than to define a group, then the non-numeric approach is probably fine)

Comment: Hi mozway, Thanks. Yes, I have used the same example from the documentation and got confused about the summary. Using `astype` on the above example, if the datatype is set as `datetime` then summary is `numeric` and if the datatype is set as `object` then summary is `non-numeric`. So, In general while performing analysis on such column, do we set datatype as `datetime` or `object`, which is preferred?

Comment: I added some extra info on how `describe` works, internally a check is made and different functions are used based on the dtype, so make sure to use the dtype that suits your needs. `datetime` dtype is probably more meaningful than `object` (unless you purely want to consider your dates as a few categoricals?).

Comment: Hi mozway, sorry for the trouble. I am new to data analysis and understand `dtype` [`datetime` or `object/category`] will depend on the problem statement and usecase. I was googling more to get clarity on this but unfortunately did not find much information/usecases to explain this difference.I did not understand this line `and their absolute value is not meaningful other than to define a group,`, can you explain please?

Comment: Let's take this the other way around, why do you need to run describe on a datetime column?

Comment: I am performing `univariate analysis` for each column. So I created 2 lists, numeric and non-numeric(object, category, datetime) and calling `describle()` to display details.

Comment: But which information do you want to extract from your analysis?

Comment: Is it ok for you to move this discussion to chat, I got warning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255086/discussion-between-mozway-and-winter).